# How can I get information about suspended or deleted video with YouTube's API?

Tags: python, r, api, youtube, rstudio

Some of my workmates asked me to get some information which they say that are reachable with YouTube's API. They don't code and asked for my help. I checked online, and it seems that these information are not available.

- General activities of someone's channel, including the URL and date
  of uploaded and deleted videos;
- Information of deleted or suspended videos of someone's channel;
- Reason that is related to the suspended videos;
- Number of reports and type of reports related to someone's channel.

Some information are available when it's related to your own channel, but not to someone's channel.

Is this right? Or can we get these informations with YouTube's API?

```
app_id <- ""
app_secret <- ""
yt_oauth(app_id, app_secret, token = "")
get_all_comments(video_id = "zVzhy3-clXI")
comments <- get_all_comments(video_id = "zVzhy3-clXI")
COMMENTS1 <- get_all_comments(video_id = "zVzhy3-clXI")
write.csv(COMMENTS1, file = "youtubecomments.csv")
```

Comment: The code about getting the comments is working properly. I don't have a code to get the activities or de suspended videos, because I didn't find out how I can do this.